# INDY command handler. Success response with a parameter

Tags: delphi, indy10

I followed the demo and things are working just fine.  My client has a single function to send commands to the server and handle the response.

That was fine for the first few command and I handle it by

```
  var result : String;
  TCPclient.SendCmd(theMessage);
  TCPclient.GetResponse(Result);

  if Result <> 'OK' then ....
```

Where the server is sending

```
ASender.Reply.SetReply(200, 'OK');  ... or ...
ASender.Reply.SetReply(400, 'NAK');
```

Now, I want to add a new command and the result will be either NAK or ACK **PLUS** a value 0, 1 or 2

I am hazy on response codes which seem to have two parameters, one numerical and one textual ....

I *could* just kludge and send 'Ok0', 'OK1', or 'OK2', but that is very ugly (and probably A Bad Thing)

I think I though to use 200 for success and send 0, 1 or 2 in the textual parameter (or use 'OK' and send 0, 1 or 2 as numeric code, or use 200, 201, 202 as numeral code)?

Can someone please help me understand what I ought to be coding and why? (Or just point me at a URL) Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SendCmd()` reads the response from the server for you, so DO NOT call `GetResponse()` after `SendCmd()` unless the server actually sends two separate responses.

Responses typically take the form:

```
<Response Code> <Optional Text>
```

Where the response code is either a number or a textual keyword.

If the server sends numeric response codes, handle it like this:

Server:

```
// sends:
//
//  200 1
//
ASender.Reply.SetReply(200, '1');
```

Client:

```
if TCPclient.SendCmd(theMessage) = 200 then
  Value := StrToInt(TCPclient.LastCmdResult.Text.Text);
```

Or:

```
// raises an exception if a non-200 response is received
TCPclient.SendCmd(theMessage, 200);
Value := StrToInt(TCPclient.LastCmdResult.Text.Text);
```

If the server sends textual response codes, handle it like this:

Server:

```
// sends:
//
//  OK 1
//
ASender.Reply.SetReply('OK', '1');
```

Client:

```
if TCPclient.SendCmd(theMessage, '') = 'OK' then
  Value := StrToInt(TCPclient.LastCmdResult.Text.Text);
```

Or:

```
// raises an exception if a non-OK response is received
TCPclient.SendCmd(theMessage, ['OK']);
Value := StrToInt(TCPclient.LastCmdResult.Text.Text);
```

The optional text of the response, if present, can be accessed in the `TCPclient.LastCmdResult.Text` property, which is a `TStrings` as it is possible to send multi-line responses in the form:

```
<Response Code>-<Optional Text>
<Response Code>-<Optional Text>
...
<Response Code> <Optional Text>
```

Server:

```
// sends:
//
//  200-The value is
//  200 1
//
ASender.Reply.SetReply(200, 'The value is');
ASender.Reply.Text.Add('1');
```

Client:

```
TCPclient.SendCmd(theMessage, 200);
Value := StrToInt(TCPclient.LastCmdResult.Text[1]);
```

You can also send secondary multi-line text after the responses in this form:

```
<Response Code> <Optional Text>
<Secondary Text>
.
```

Server:

```
// sends:
//
//  200 Data follows
//  Hello world
//  How are you?
//  .
//
ASender.Reply.SetReply(200, 'Data follows');
ASender.Reply.Response.Add('Hello world');
ASender.Reply.Response.Add('How are you?');
```

Client:

```
TCPclient.SendCmd(theMessage, 200);
TCPclient.IOHandler.Capture(SomeTStringsObj);
```

Comment: +1 and the answer. Remy, thank you very much for taking the tme to give such a detailed answer. I hope that it will serve to help others.